# Delete Facebook account using Cypress

Tags: testing, integration-testing, cypress

I'd like to delete my Facebook account, but actually, I'd like to obfuscate my data first.

Cypress seems to be a great fit. However, I'm not getting past the login: "Your request couldn't be processed"

Here is my code:

```
describe('obfuscate data', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.visit('https://facebook.com');
    cy.get('#email').type(email);
    cy.get('#pass').type(password);
    cy.get('form button').click();
  });

  it('should be logged in', () => {
    cy.contains('What\'s on your mind, XXXX?');
  });
});
```

What is different in Cypress, from an actual browser? When I open a new browser tab in Cypress and go to Facebook.com, I can manually log in fine.

[Facebook login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Mak.png)

Comment: Hi @lolman45 your password is visible on your screenshot. If you use this as your personal account please change it asap. And from next time please blackout or blur personal information.

Answer (score 2):

Using cypress on 3rd party sites (ones you do not control) is highly discouraged: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Visiting-external-sites

Also, I'm pretty sure deleting accounts using automated scripts also breaks couple of facebooks terms and conditions in case you care.